# Rspec Array_extensions Class or Instance Methods

Tags: ruby, arrays, class, rspec, instance

I could use some help on writing a program that will pass this spec file.

As I understand it, class methods are denoted with a ‘.’, while instance methods with a ‘#’. Here, the methods are denoted with a ‘#’, and I assume ‘[]’ can be translated literally as ‘Array.new’. In that case, how can I write an instance method  such as ‘sum’ - which runs through the array and computes the sum - which doesn’t operate on an instance variable but on the object itself? In other words, not an attribute like

```
def sum
    @sum.each do …
```

but something like

```
def sum
    self.each do …
```

I have considered making these class methods, but this has given me the error that ‘self’ cannot be changed, when I try to reassign the values in the array itself, in the ‘square!’ method.

My question is, how do I solve this dilemma, and are these class methods or instance methods?

Thank you.

Here is the spec file:

```
require "array_extensions" # we don't call it "array.rb" since that would be confusing

describe Array do

  describe "#sum" do
    it "has a #sum method" do
      [].should respond_to(:sum)
    end

    it "should be 0 for an empty array" do
      [].sum.should == 0
    end

    it "should add all of the elements" do
      [1,2,4].sum.should == 7
    end
  end

  describe '#square' do
    it "does nothing to an empty array" do
      [].square.should == []
    end

    it "returns a new array containing the squares of each element" do
      [1,2,3].square.should == [1,4,9]
    end
  end

  describe '#square!' do
    it "squares each element of the original array" do
      array = [1,2,3]
      array.square!
      array.should == [1,4,9]
    end
  end

end
```

Here is my code:

```
class Array
  attr_accessor :sum

  def sum
    total = 0
    []s.each { |x| total += x }
    @sum = total
  end
  def self.square
    if self.empty?
      self
    else
      newArray = self.map { |x| x*x }
  end
  def self.square!
    self = self.map { |x| x*x }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a very succinct way to satisfy your rspec requirements:

```
class Array
  def sum
    inject(0, &:+)
  end
  def square
    map { |x| x * x }
  end
  def square!
    map! { |x| x * x }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

`self.each` or just `each` is correct:

```
def sum
  total = 0
  self.each { |x| total += x }
  # or
  # each { |x| total += x }
  total
end
```

in a class should work. But there's an easier way,

```
def sum
  inject { |a, x| a + x }   # (or self.inject)
end
```

`def self.square` will define a class method - and inside that, `self` is `Array` (i.e. instance of `Class`) - and since those don't have `map` method, you can't do that. You need just `def square` to define it:

```
def square
  map { |x| x * x }   # (or self.map)
end
```

With `square!`, you can't replace `self`, but you can replace each of its elements.

```
def square!
  (0...length).each { |i| self[i] *= self[i] }   # or self.length
  self   # just so it returns a pretty value and not a range
end
```

Comment: `def sum; inject(:+); end`

Comment: @ArieShaw: Indeed, even shorter.